# Create multiple-choice list by pressing on EditText

Tags: android, layout, text, menu

Suppose that we have

```
EditText editTextTitle = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textTitle);
```

When the user touches the text field the keyboard appears in order to write some text. Instead of this I want to appear a [multiple choice list](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#AddingAList) with some elements. When the user confirms the selected items then I want to pass the text of these elements on the editTextTitle. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, simply set an OnClickListener on the EditText to open your custom dialog.  Also use a callback to assign the user's selected choice to the EditText (assuming you want to do this).

---

**Addition**

> how can I pass the onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) in the onClickListener?

[`onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html#onCreateDialog%28android.os.Bundle%29) is a method in DialogFragment, so it's impossible to give one answer to cover every way you could create your Fragment... But let's assume you already have a DialogFragment named `dialogFrag` initialized and ready to go:

```
editTextTitle.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick (View v) {
        dialogFrag.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: yes but how can I invoke the onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) in the onClickListener?

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use a spinner. which serves the exact with a nice look.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html

Comment: ohh I had forgotten this! That's also perfect!

Comment: I think that it is possible to select more than one items. Because in the example I see only one choice (home). For example I want to have home, office, ... in one field.